# equation of a tangent line to a given curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $y=x^{9}e^{−x}$ at the point $(1,e^{-1})$.

Would I have to differentiate it using the product rule?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the equation to a function at a point (x,y) is given by Y - f(x) = f'(x) (X - x). Then, establish the expression of f'(x) for f(x)=x^9 Exp[-x] and plug in the formula x=0, y=1/e and the value of f'(x) for x=0. I hope you checked that for x=0, y=1/e.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Differentiate (with the product rule) in order to find the slope.

Remember that $(fg)'=f'g + fg'$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for you problem is in below link and follow the steps. You will be able to find the answer and very easy
http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Equation-of-a-Tangent-Line

Comment: 9e^-x^2(x-1)+(1/e) Wouldn't that be my answer?